# CSS correction for IE

Tags: asp.net, css

```
     input[type=file] {
position: relative;
text-align: right;
-moz-opacity:0 ;
filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
opacity: 2;
z-index: 2;
      }

     <asp:FileUpload ID="filResume" class="file" runat="server" width="600" size="81" /> <br />
```

Previously I had the Opacity : 0 in mY style sheet and I was not able to see the File upload control at all.

So After changing the Opacity : 2 I was able to see the file upload control in fireforx only. The file upload control is not showing up in IE. (IE 9) How can I make the file uplaod control visible in IE??

Comment: Do you know what `opacity` means?

Comment: ... and in which units it's measured in FF and IE?

Comment: Oh, and don't use -moz-opacity, that's so last decade. Just opacity will do.

Comment: Hi Lister - I had the same exact style n my style sheet and my file upload control is visible in firefox and not visible in Internet explorer.

Comment: I don't know  in which units it's measured. But it can be from 0 to 10 something like that I guess.

Comment: I changed the styling to

Comment: filter:alpha(opacity:70); 
opacity: 70; And the control is visible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to remove the `opacity`.

Comment: filter:alpha(opacity:70); 
opacity: 70;

Comment: I changed the styling to above and I was able to see the control in IE.

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like it to be fully visible just remove opacity, moz-opacity, and filter from your css.

It's not showing up in IE because IE uses filter:alpha(opacity) to determine opacity, and your filter:alpha(opacity) is set to 0(invisible).

Opacity is measured between 0 and 1, with 0 being invisible and 1 being visible.

filter:alpha(opacity) is measured between 0 and 100.

hope that helps